# How to create a parser which means any char not in ['(',')','{','}'], in PetitParserDart?

Tags: dart, petitparser

I want to define a parser which accept any char except `['(', ')', '{', '}']` in [PetitParserDart](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart).

I tried:

```
char('(').not() & char(')').not() & char('{').not() & char('}')
```

I'm not sure if it's correct, and is it any simple way to do this? (something like `chars('(){}').neg()`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches anything, but the characters listed after the caret `^`. It is the character class of all characters without the listed ones:

```
pattern('^(){}');
```

This also works (note the `.not()` on the last character, and the `any()` to actually consume the character):

```
char('(').not() & char(')').not() & char('{').not() & char('}').not() & any()
```

And this one works as well:

```
anyIn('(){}').neg()
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(anyIn('(){}').not() & any()).pick(1)
```

And another alternative is:

```
(char('(') | char(')') | char('{') | char('}')).neg()
```

Except for the second example, all examples return the parsed character (this can be easily fixed, but I wanted to stay close to your question). The first example is probably the easiest to understand, but depending on context you might prefer one of the alternatives.